# Java fails to open files with errno=1

Tags: java, debugging

I'm on OS X 10.11.6 “El Capitan” and I need to use a USB token to digitally sign bank orders. It relies on Java, but it’s experiencing problems.

I have debugged the Java console and that’s the result; as you can see, the error is "No suitable image found. Open() failed with errno=1" that points to a .jnilib file (maybe a digital certificate?)

Here’s what the debugger tells:

```
basic: Applet inizializzata
basic: Avvio applet
basic: rollup prestazioni completato
SIGNAPPLET : isStarted false
SIGNAPPLET : start() : inizio
SIGNAPPLET : libraryName=libbit4opki.dylib
SIGNAPPLET : pathWrapperClient=libpkcs11wrapper.jnilib
SIGNAPPLET : initializing manager pkcs11   /Users/tyrexionibus/postecert/libbit4opki.dylib wrapper path /Users/tyrexionibus/postecert/libpkcs11wrapper.jnilib
SIGNAPPLET : ERRORE Throwable : /Users/tyrexionibus/postecert/libpkcs11wrapper.jnilib: dlopen(/Users/tyrexionibus/postecert/libpkcs11wrapper.jnilib, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/tyrexionibus/postecert/libpkcs11wrapper.jnilib: open() failed with errno=1
SIGNAPPLET : showCERTIFICATEPanel
it.postecom.pkcs.pkcs11.GestoreHWSW$Exc: Throwable : /Users/tyrexionibus/postecert/libpkcs11wrapper.jnilib: dlopen(/Users/tyrexionibus/postecert/libpkcs11wrapper.jnilib, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/tyrexionibus/postecert/libpkcs11wrapper.jnilib: open() failed with errno=1
    at it.postecom.pkcs.pkcs11.GestoreHWSW.<init>(GestoreHWSW.java:50)
    at it.postecom.pkcs.pkcs11.GestoreHWSW.getInstance(GestoreHWSW.java:59)
    at it.postecom.bpiol.applet.SignApplet.start(SignApplet.java:239)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.start(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
SIGNAPPLET : start() - fine
SIGNAPPLET : isStarted true
```

I’m at a dead end with it, I can’t deal with it anymore. Tried different versions of JRE, even legacy ones, with no effort. Tried uninstalling JRE and JDK, and rolling back to Apple Java 1.6 legacy, with no results.

Can you help?

Comment: This is probably a permissions error, errno 1 means that the operation is not permitted by the operating system. In other words, the Java program is not allowed to open the library.

Comment: Have you considered looking up `errno` value 1?

Answer (score 0):

.jnilib is not a certificate, but a native library your application is trying to call through the Java Native Interface (JNI). Obviously some code is not pure Java, but needs some OS-specific code, most likely to access the hardware of your crypto stick.

- Is the library at the path given in the error message?
- Is the library at that location an OSX binary?
- Does it have execute permissions?

Comment: How do I give execute permissions, for Java, with regard to that .jnilib library?

Comment: Sorry, OS X is not my os... On Linux I'd use `chmod u+x <file>` (or `chmod a+x` to give everybody execute permissions). This should also work in a console on OS X. Google tells me that you also can set file permissions in the Info dialog in the File menu.

But did you check whether the file is really an OS X-library? I couldn't really verify whether execute permissions are necessary for a jnilib on OS X.